# drupal website css folder 500 error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal

Drupal website is not loading css file.

I went to that path and all files are there.

I did change the permission of css folder still its giving 500 error.

It was working before.
Using Godaddy Hosting.

Comment: If you request the CSS file directly in the browser do you get the 500 error? I think we probably need to see you .htaccess file. What does your error log report?

Comment: @w3d : yes it gives 500 error. and nothing in error log.
here is the htaccess https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tvAWP7_8xzF9CiN0ioIkAARgW-crJ-xKCW4P1dCENeY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you have a corresponding `*.css.gz` file? (Are you sending compressed files?)

Comment: @w3d : yes i do have .gz file.. updated the image on above doc file you can check.. and to be honest with you i dont know the answer or  (Are you sending compressed files?)  this all thing was working fine it stopped automatically

Comment: Your .htaccess file looks OK as far as I can see. The only thing regarding the CSS files is that if there is a cached `.css.gz` file, that will be served instead. So I was going to suggest perhaps deleting (or renaming) that file in case there is a problem with the compressed/cache file? If it "was working before" then maybe GoDaddy have "updated" something?

Comment: @w3d I just added one dummy style.css file and when i try to access the same from browser it still give me 500 error

Comment: @w3d I just tried to access .css.gz file from browser and it worked but when i tri to access the .css file it gives 500 error and when i see the viewsource of website its taking css file

Comment: You need to clear cache and|or disable CSS and JS caching.

Comment: you might also make sure there isn't a .htaccess file hanging out in the default/files/css directory accidentally. Are you able to add a .txt file to the css directory and get to it directly? if not, there is a directory setting, if so it's likely a cache issue and clearing cache as other stated should help.